# Why are these returning the same values of this string?

Tags: javascript

Here is my issue I'm learning JavaScript and the problem is understanding why these are returning the same values? What I don't understand is the `lastIndexOf()`, it is returning the same value of 10, shouldn't it be 12 or 8? The value of b is correct it's 10.. However, "C" `lastIndexOf()` is NOT.

```
var a = "This is a test string.";
var b = a.indexOf("test");
var c = a.lastIndexOf("test");

document.write(b + "<br>");
document.write(c);
```

Comment: Because `"test"` starts at position `10` - `lastIndexOf` doesn't take the last character - it takes the last instance.

Comment: `test` appears only once, so its first and last occurrence are at the same position ... try it with `"This is a test test string."`

Comment: So if i had test in a String twice like "Hello this is test number 1, hello this is test number 2. "  It would show up test number 2 as the last instance because it was the last "test" word in the string? So indexOf in this case would be 14 and the lastIndexOf would be 10?

Comment: You last assumption is false, and I don't even know where you get 14 and 10 from. Just read the answers here below which are all pretty clear...

Comment: Try it with "test" in the string twice.  For instance a="This test is a test string." and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake here is my correction
'
    var a = "This is a test string test.";
    var b = a.indexOf("test");
    var c = a.lastIndexOf("test");

    document.write(b + "<br>");
    document.write(c);
'


OUTPUT is 10 and 22

Comment: I get it now it always starts from the beginning and counts from "0" if "test" occurs twice the "indexOf" counts where the first letter of it starts. If there is test numourous times it will count the last word of "test" in the string and starts from the first letter.. eg "THis is test and test" indexOf = 8 | lastIndexOf = 17        ||| Thanks Guys I Get it now!!!

Answer (score 6):

The string only contains one instance of "test" so the results for `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` should be the same.

`lastIndexOf` finds the index (counting from the front of the string) of the first character of the *last* instance of the substring in the other string.

It doesn't find the index of the last character in the substring.

It doesn't find the number of characters from the end of the other string.

Answer (score 0):

lastIndexOf - Will return the last occurrence of the STRING. Not the last character of the string. So, will return the position where the "test" string begins.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is correct.
In your example it just happens that "test" has the same index for `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` because you have the string "test" just one time. Both javascript functions return the index of the start of the string.
Hope it was clear enough.